# Initializing an iterator to a position within a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am trying to initialize a `vector<string>::iterator it` to a position `x` in my vector. It seems I can only position my iterator to the first element of the vector thanks to `it=vector.begin();`.

What if I want the iterator to start working from the position x? How can I move it? I don't want my iterator to go through the whole vector when I already know I can find what I'm looking for starting from the position x.

I tried initializing the iterator as `it=vector.begin()` and then moving it to x with `advance(it,x);` but it's not working. If I try to print `*it` it won't return any value.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is `x`? If it is an index, you can use `v.begin() + x`. If it is a vector element, you can get its index as `&x - &v[0]`.

Comment: yes it is an index. I tried this already and won't print anyway

Comment: @stardust: if it's not printing anything then provide a minimal verifiable example that shows your problem, because we lack the required input since the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Right, if it is not printing anything, that element could be empty or blank. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::vector` support random access iterators, this means that you can directly add a specified amount to an iterator, eg

```
auto it = vector.begin() + 4;
```

In any case `std::advance` should definitely work:

```
auto it = vector.begin();
std::advance(it, 4);
```

And also `std::next` if you don't want to modify an existing iterator:

```
auto it = std::next(vector.begin(), 4);
```

Comment: `std::advance` returns `void`.

Comment: @user2079303: yes, I mixed up with `std::next`.

Comment: I tried both solution and yet it pritns NULL I guess. does begin refers to the first position so I shoud add `auto it = vector.begin() +x-1` ?

Comment: @stardust This is why you need to edit your post and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can pinpoint additional issues with your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact position, you can use `it + x`. Other approach is to use `advance()` as you write in the question. The following [does work](http://ideone.com/r7qxsx):

```
std::vector<int> a{10,20,30,40};
auto it1 = a.begin() + 2;
auto it2 = a.begin();
advance(it2, 2);
cout << *it1 << " " << *it2;
```